# How to access passed Enum argument in Swift 3

Tags: swift

I'm having some trouble accessing a parameter that is passed with an enum.

Generic RequestType, more will be included.

```
enum RequestType {
  case flagging(api : FlaggingRequestType)
}
```

Here is my enum that accepts another FlaggingRequestType (another enum  that accepts a string parameter)

```
enum FlaggingRequestType {
  case getFlag(api : String)
}

protocol Requestable {
  var requestType : RequestType { get set }
}
```

Here I build my flagging request

```
let flaggingRequest = RequestBuilder.buildFlaggingRequest(flagRequest: .getFlag(api: "http://www.apiworld.com"))
```

Here is my method to actually sends the request from another method.

```
func sendRequest(for apiRequest : Requestable) {
  switch apiRequest.requestType {
  case .flagging:
  self.flaggingAPI(for: apiRequest)
 }
}
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to access the value passed in the `api` parameter found in `apiRequest`/ `flaggingRequest`. Is this possible? I hope this is clear :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's a great link for enums with associated values https://appventure.me/2015/10/17/advanced-practical-enum-examples/#sec-1-5

```
func sendRequest(for apiRequest : Requestable) {
    switch apiRequest.requestType {
    case .flagging(let api):
        // access api value here
        self.flaggingAPI(for: apiRequest)
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

#### "Nested" pattern matching & value binding: `case .one(.two(let val))`

If, for a given instance of a type that conforms to `Requestable`, your single goal is to access the associated `String` value of the "inner" `FlaggingRequestType` instance (for a known inner `case`), you can use nested pattern matching and binding in a single `case`, e.g. used not only in a `switch` buy, say, an `if` statement.

```
// your example setup
enum FlaggingRequestType {
    case getFlag(api : String)
}

protocol Requestable {
    var requestType : RequestType { get set }
}

enum RequestType {
    case flagging(api : FlaggingRequestType)
}
    
// dummy type conforming to 'Requestable'
struct Foo : Requestable {
    var requestType: RequestType =
        .flagging(api: .getFlag(api: "http://www.apiworld.com"))
}

// Q: how to find the nested "http://www.apiworld.com" String
//    from a 'Foo' instance?
let foo = Foo()

// A: use nested pattern matching, e.g. in a single 'if' statement
if case .flagging(.getFlag(let api)) = foo.requestType {
    print(api) // http://www.apiworld.com
}
```

You can naturally make use of the nested pattern matching also in the cases of a `switch` statement:

```
switch foo.requestType {
case .flagging(.getFlag(let api)): print(api) // http://www.apiworld.com
// ...
default : () // in non-exhaustive pattern matching above
}
```

In case the associated value of different types of the `FlaggingRequestType` are of the same type, and also the same expected usage, this nested binding can be a useful alternative to several nested `switch` statements. E.g., if extending the example setup above to:

```
enum FlaggingRequestType {
    case getFlag(api : String)
    case getHandle(api : String)
    case getId(id: Int)
}
```

We could apply nested pattern matching in a single `switch` statement, where one single `case` could cover binding associated values for several different cases of the inner enum, given that those associated values have the same type.

```
switch foo.requestType {
case .flagging(.getFlag(let api)),
     .flagging(.getHandle(let api)): print(api) // api is 'String', a flag or a handle
case .flagging(.getId(let id)):      print(id)  // id is 'Int'
// ...
default : () // in case of non-exhaustive pattern matching above
}
```

---

Finally, note that you might want to consider using type constrained generics for your `sendRequest` method, rather than typing out a protocol to be used as type.

```
func sendRequest<T: Requestable>(for apiRequest : T) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 6):

Since it is nested, you will have to do nested switch cases, like this:

```
switch apiRequest {
case .flagging(let value):
    switch value {
    case .getFlag(let api):
        print(api) // api is the string passed in the associated value
        break
    }
    break
}
```

**UPDATE**

Swift has changed the behaviour around switch statements, so cases are no longer falling through to the next case. This means you no longer need to explicitly `break`. Instead, if you want the old behaviour, you can use the `fallthrough` keyword, to make your execution continue into the next case.

You can also unwrap cases in the outer switch:

```
switch apiRequest {
case .flagging(.getFlag(let api)):
    print(api) // api is the string passed in the associated value
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Swift UI

```
enum Action {
case INCREMENT
case DECREMENT
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var counter = 0
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                handleIncreaseDecrease(action: Action.DECREMENT)
            }) {
                Text("-")
            }
            Text("\(counter)")
            Button(action: {
                handleIncreaseDecrease(action: Action.INCREMENT)
            }) {
                Text("+")
            }
        }
    }
    
func handleIncreaseDecrease(action:Action) {
    if (action == Action.INCREMENT) {
        counter += 1
    } else {
        counter -= 1
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The question is about associated values of enums. This answer does not adress that. Recommend deletion.